# how to sort json array based on most frequent occurance

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sorting

I need to find out which topping combinations are most popular, I need to list the 20 most frequently ordered pizza configurations(listing each topping):

```
[
  {
    "toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
     "mozzarella cheese",
     "bacon",
     "beef",
     "onions",
     "pineapple"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "bacon"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "sausage",
      "beef"
    ]
  },
```

Here is what I have tried: I tried to count the occurrence of each topping - but that totally failed.

Comment: Can you add some code demonstrating how you are working with the json?

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonOutput = loadJSONFromAsset();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Pizza>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<Pizza> pizzaList = (List<Pizza>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code to make it easier for other viewers to understand your code. Thanks